# Kotlin run on Android Studio failed prompt "Gradle sync failed: Connection timed out: connect Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-2.3

Kotlin run on Android Studio fialed and tell me "Gradle sync failed: Connection timed out: connect Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)",but if i just new android project and not configure kotlin configuration that ok.

My operational like this:

```
1.Install kotlin plugin .
2.configure kotlin in project .
3.convert java file to kotlin file
4.Run "app" failed
```

**My IDE version:**

![IDE version ][1]

**My configution**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  //kotlin config 
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.huawei.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: `$kotlin_version` is not defined?

Comment: @cricket_007 Is this defined?                      

 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }

Comment: Yes, now if you click on "Show Log" what information is there?

Comment: @cricket_007 the log detail :

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding `jcenter()` to `repositories` block of root `build.gradle` file:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()// <-- Add jcenter
}
```